# "Some mandatory parameters are missing" Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've having trouble passing off an object to my 'edit' view in Laravel 4. The URL is generated correctly "localhost/edit/1" however this is the returned error:

```
Some manadatory parameters are missing ("offer") to generate a URL for route "get edit/{offer}
```

My related routes.php snippet:

```
Route::get('edit/{offer}','OfferController@edit');
```

The OfferController@edit action:

```
public function edit(Offer $offer)
{
    return View::make('edit',compact('offer'));
}
```

Just some extra detail, here's the snippet from the 'index' view that initiates the action:

```
<a href = "{{ action('OfferController@edit', $offer->id) }}">Edit</a>
```

I should also mention when I remove the Blade form in '/views/edit.blade.php' the view is created, including the header which specifies the $offer->id:

```
<h1>Edit Offer {{ $offer->id }}</h1>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't know if this is your issue or not, but in your route, you have mismatched braces, `{]`, also, in your edit function, you are missing a single tick after offer in `compact`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but that's not the case in the code. My dev laptop doesn't have internet at the moment I had to post from a desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an array to `action()`:

```
<a href = "{{ action('OfferController@edit', array($offer->id)) }}">Edit</a>
```

Comment: I tried that, same error. I've also tried changing the OfferController@edit action to accept just $offer as a parameter and that doesn't work either. I'm following a reference character for character and it's not working.

Comment: Just tested it here to be sure and it works. So you must be doing something different on your end. Had to change some names, but: http://puu.sh/5hk2m.png

Answer (score 1):

Your Edit function needs to be changed. You are passing id in link, but expects Instance of `Offer` in `edit` function. Assuming `Offer` is an `Eloquent` model,

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $offer = Offer::find($id);
    return View::make('edit',compact('offer'));
}
```

Hope this helps.